# Не работает TemplateSelector

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Есть `ItemsControl`

```
   <Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="control"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}"
                  ItemTemplate="{x:Bind CellTemplate, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource SimpleSelector}}">

        <!--Хочу сделать так-->
        <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        ContentTemplate="{Binding SelectedCollageTemplate, Converter={StaticResource CollageTemplateSelector}}" />

<!--Как было-->
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:SimplePanel SelectedCollage="{Binding SelectedCollage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                SelectedCollagePattern="{Binding SelectedCollagePattern}">
            <controls:SimplePanel.Background>
         <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                     ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/Background/5.jpg" />
            </controls:SimplePanel.Background>
                </controls:SimplePanel>          
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>


</Grid>
```

Задача в том, чтобы выбрать нужную панель в зависимости от того, что вернет конвертер. Если просто вписать SimplePanel, все работает

Когда использую селектор, в класс панели даже не заходи в конструктор

Добавил селектор:

```
 <templateSelector:CollageTemplateSelector x:Key="CollageTemplateSelector"
                                          SimpleTemplate="{StaticResource SimpleTemplate}"
                                          ShapeTemplate="{StaticResource ShapeTemplate}"/>
```

И переместил в соответствующий DataTemplate свою панель:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SimpleTemplate">
    <controls:SimplePanel
                      SelectedCollage="{Binding SelectedCollage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedCollagePattern="{Binding SelectedCollagePattern}">
        <controls:SimplePanel.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                    ImageSource="ms-appx:///Images/Background/5.jpg" />
        </controls:SimplePanel.Background>
    </controls:SimplePanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Конвертер отдает SimplePanel как и должен, но сам контролл не запускается. В чем проблема?

Сам селектор:

```
   public class CollageTemplateSelector : IValueConverter
{
    public DataTemplate SimpleTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ShapeTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate CreativeTemplate { get; set; }


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var result = SimpleTemplate;
        var collage = value as Collage;
        if (collage != null)
        {
            switch (collage.Type)
            {
                case CollageTemplates.Simple:
                    result = this.SimpleTemplate;
                    break;
                case CollageTemplates.Shape:
                    result = this.ShapeTemplate;
                    break;
                case CollageTemplates.Creative:
                    result = this.CreativeTemplate;
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: А куда вы добавили селектор? Покажите код вокруг.

Comment: И что значит не запускается?

Comment: Селектор добавил в вопрос

Comment: @VladD Точка останова на конструкторе не срабатывает. Логика реализованная в классе не работает(не вызывается)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас не Темплейт-селектор вовсе, а конвертер, который вы пытаетесь использовать вместо него.

Темплейт-селектор подключается через:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource=ContentControlTemplateSelector}"/>
```

И выглядит вот так:

```
public class ContentControlTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate NormalTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate WarningTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        var obj = item as Tender;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            ...
            return ...;
        }
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Конвертер при этом не нужен.